# Why are qemu static binaries required inside a Docker container when running on a foreign architecture?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, arm, fedora, qemu

I have a Fedora 26 workstation and a Ubuntu 16.04 server. On the former, I can run `docker run -it --rm arm32v7/python:3.6.2-slim /bin/sh` with `qemu-user-static` installed but when I try to run it on Ubuntu I get:

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I can remedy this by adding `-v /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static`. What baffles me is that I don't need to do this with Fedora. Why is that? Is there any way I could achieve the same with Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know yet as to why this difference, but looking at this url https://gist.github.com/Manu343726/ca0ceb224ea789415387 it looks like it is needed

Comment: Yes, but my main issue is "How did this work on Fedora using Docker installed from Docker's official Fedora repository". As it stands, I would have to copy the qemu static binary to the project directory, which totally destroys the simple "docker-compose up" approach and necessitates the use of a Makefile or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute arm code natively you should have an active entry in binfmt_misc

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
flags: OC
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

Check if your Fedora and Ubuntu configurations are different

Answer (score 0):

The main reason this did not work on Ubuntu (16.04 or 18.04) is because these distributons do not have the "fixed binary" flag on by default in the binfmt support files. Additionally, Ubuntu 16.04 requires a newer kernel from a new hardware enablement stack.

[This repository](https://github.com/computermouth/qemu-static-conf) helped me easily fix the binfmt configuration on Ubuntu.